# Network issue after clean install of Ubuntu Server & choosing DHCP

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers, server, dhcp

I've had this old laptop that I used as a windows server, I've had my mail-, ftp- and http server running on it. But once everything worked. The fun of having a server was gone. So this weekend I thought; let's install Linux on it and try to get it working that way!

But I'm afraid I got in over my head, while installing Ubuntu server, the installer asks if I want to set up my network connection. I chose to use DHCP and after a minute it told me that it was unable to obtain an IP address. Since I was at work, I thought it had something to do with the complex network and I skipped that step.

But now I'm at home and I still cannot get an internet connection.
I'm new to all this but I will list some things that I think maybe important.

```
cat /etc/network/interfaces

# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system 
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface  
auto lo  
iface lo inet loopback
```

.

```
ip link show

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP) mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000 link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00 00:00:00:00 

2: enp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000 link/ether 01:7d:7b:bc:7e:ee brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff 

3: wlp2s0b1: (330008031. HULTICHSI) <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000 link/ether e0:06:e6:3f:01:04 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

And if i try:

```
lspci -v

// a lot of devices //

01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 05) 
    Subsystem: acer Incorporated [ALI] RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller 
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 29 
    I/0 ports at 4000 [size=256] 
    Memory at 40004000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=4K] 
    Memory at 40000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied> 
    Kernel driver in use: r8169 
    Kernel modules: r8169 

02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Limited BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01) 
    Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Netuork adapter 
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17 
    Memory at 44000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K] 
    Capabilities: <access denied> 
    Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge 
    Kernel modules: bcma 

03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. TS5209 PCI Express Card Reader (rev. 01) 
    Subsystem: acer Incorporated [0L1] 3185209 PCI Express Card Reader 
    ...
```

I mostly tried to make a connection over UTP, but tried a bit of wireless with no success. It is not the cable, I tried two different networks and any other PC will work fine on the same UTP.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the current contents of your /etc/network/interfaces file (`cat /etc/network/interfaces`)

Comment: Try to get a DHCP address manually: `sudo dhclient -v enp1s0`. If that works, you can add the following entry to `/etc/network/interfaces`: `auto enp1s0 iface enp1s0 inet dhcp`

Comment: Thank you, @Simon Sudler. That did the trick! I got everything up and running and am able to log into my console from my work computer. Now I can start learning and exploring the world of Linux!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add the DHCP address manually with the following command:

```
sudo dhclient -v enp1s0
```

If the DHCP client returns a valid IP address from the DHCP server, you can add the following lines to the `/etc/network/interfaces` file:

```
auto enp1s0
iface enp1s0 inet dhcp
```